# Como criar um numerador de páginas?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

Estou desenvolvendo uma página "News" com várias notícias, sendo que será exibido somente 9 notícias por página, acima disso, deverá ir para a página 2 e assim sucessivamente... como faço isso?

[image: Modelo]

Comment: Isso se chama "paginação". Que eu sabia, com "HTML puro" não tem como fazer. Talvez usar linguagens como PHP, Python ou Ruby vai ajudar nessa tarefa de paginação.

Comment: Legal Wallace, sou iniciante na área... rsrsrs... poderia me explicar como isso é feito?

Comment: @AdrianoAquino, você pode fazer esta paginacao apenas com HTML, CSS e JavaScript, porém vai precisar de uma aplicação web (C#, Ruby, PHP, Java) para consultar o conteudo a ser exibido.

Comment: De onde vem esses dados? Eles vem de um banco de dados? Ou são de uma página estática que você criou?

Comment: Pensei em fazer em HTML, mas deverá ser usado MySql com PHP, mas tenho pouca prática, ainda estou aprendendo, o que você sugere?

Comment: @AdrianoAquino Bom dia, caso você utilize php aqui está uma dica sobre paginação (está bem simples e comentado): http://www.sergiotoledo.com.br/tutoriais/programacao-php/paginacao-php

Comment: É importante sabermos a linguagem, para até mesmo mudarmos a TAG da sua pergunta. Ela induz a pensar que você está tentando paginar os dados apenas pelo HTML

Comment: @AdrianoAquivo, para o lado cliente você pode usar algum puglin, como eu sou um defensor ferenho do `Zurb Foundation`, te aconselho olhar o seguinte link: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/pagination.html

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, estou utilizando PHP, JS com MySQL... atualize as tags a seu critério, obrigado pelo alerta.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft, legal os links, mto util, vlw!

Answer (score 4):

vamos fazer um exemplo básico em PHP:

```
try{

    $page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    if (!$page) {
        $page = 1; // Se a "page" não existir, o seu valor é 1
    }

    $limit = 9;

    $offset = ($page * $limit) - $limit; // normaliza o offset utilizado no banco

    $pdo = new PDO('...'); // seu dados de conexão aqui

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) as count FROM noticias');


    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $number_of_pages = ceil($result['count'] / $limit); // calcula o total máximo de páginas, arredondando pra cima :)

    unset($stmt, $result);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM notiicias LIMIT {$offset}, {$limit}"); // consulta com os limites

    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



} catch(Exception $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Gerando os links no HTML:

```
    <?php for($i = 1; $i < $number_of_pages; $i++): ?>
        <a href="?<?php echo http_build_query(array('page' => $i) +  $_GET)"><?php echo $i ?></a>
   <?php endfor ?>
```

## Explicando:

- `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` é uma nova maneira de o PHP lidar com os dados vindos do cliente. Ou seja, definimos que a variável `page` virá através do método `GET`, e deve ser um valor inteiro. Ele será útil para sabermos em qual página atual estamos. Por padrão, veja que seu valor é `1`;
- O calculo de `$offset` é feito da seguinte forma. Para o usuário deve se exibir a contagem a partir de `1`, porém, no SQL, essa contagem deve ser feita a partir de `0`. Por isso utilizamos o cálculo `($page * $limit) - $limit)`: para normalizar o valor para ser utilizado no MYSQL.
- A seguir temos uma conexão com o banco através do [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
- Depois de obtermos o número de linhas existentes na tabela noticiais, calculamos qual é o número máximo de páginas que podemos gerar. Isso é feito utilizando `ceil($result['count'] / $limit`. A função `ceil` tem o trabalho de arredondar o número pra cima, pois estamos trabalhando com inteiros.
- Depois, temos o `SELECT` com um `LIMIT`, onde o primeiro argumento de `LIMIT` é o offset inicial onde vamos inciar a consulta; e o segundo argumento é o limit por página, que no caso é `9`, definido na variável `$limit`.
- E por fim, temos um `for`, que gera os links para você clicar de acordo e exibir os resultados de acordo com a página. Tentei deixar o código o máximo organizado possível. Por isso utilizei a função `http_build_query`. Ela gera dados em codificação de url através de um `array`. Quando somamos `['page' => $i] + $_GET` estamos garantindo que o valor de `page` já existente no `$_GET` não sobrescreva o valor que queremos ter como `page` dentro de `http_build_query`.

Veja por que é importante utilizar [PDO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql) ao invés das funções `mysql_*`

Para entender mais sobre a "soma de array", veja a explicação no [Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.array.php)

Comment: Foi uma breve explicação.

Comment: Uma pequena info: precisa saber que, quando usa "limit" MySQL faz o "limit" depois de filtrar tudo. Significa que se vc tem 100.000 dados, MySQL vai filtrar e ordenar os 100.000 mesmo se vc faz um "limit" de somente 10. No caso de muitas informações pode ser lento. Neste caso e melhor tentar fazer um SELECT usando um valor. Por exemplo, no caso de "filtrar por preço", criar um query com "preço menor que e maior que" e fazer evoluir o preço pagina depois pagina.

Comment: Tem certeza? Uma consulta a uma tabela com 10.000 dados me parece mais rápida quando uso o `LIMIT`!

Comment: Não, e mas lento. O que faz que vc acha que e mas rápido e porque vc olha o resultado na sua tela. No Web, tem velocidade do SQL, do PHP mas também da transmissão dos dados: quando vc faz um LIMIT do ponto da vista da SQL e mas lento, mas como vc recebe somente uma pequena quantidade de dados, o resultado "visual" e mas rápido. Por isso o problema inicia a acontecer somente quando tem muitas informações com "query" complicado.

Comment: Valeu senhores, vou olhar aqui! Abs